# Can access my server by localhost but not by ip from the same computer

Tags: networking

Am working on a development task at home.  I am running a django developoment site on my machine.  I can access it simply at

```
http://localhost:8000.
```

I decided to try and forward that port temporarily so that I can test a paypal integration.

I found that I cannot access the server from any other machine- including the machine with the server on it.  From the same browser with the webpage displayed, I get

```
`Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.1.7:8000`
```

I tried to forward the port with Windows firewall, and when that didn't work, I turned it off completely.  I figure I am missing something obvious but am not sure what it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server doesn't appear to be configured to accept traffic from the local IP address. Localhost is going to be a 127.0.0.1 address, and I would guess that http://127.0.0.1:8000 would probably work. Examine your configuration files for whatever http host service (IIS, Apache, Nginx) your server-box is using, and update the configuration to include the proper IP address it should expect traffic from. It's difficult to be precise, since you didn't give any specifics about the framework.

Comment: Yeah, turns out there is a configuration for the django development server I was not aware of.  lol  Thanks!

Comment: If anyone needs to know how to do this, python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 will accomplish it.

Comment: Happy to help Paul, I can't count the number of times I've mis-configured Apache and been left scratching my head as to why pages didn't come up.

Answer (score 0):

Use [full server name]  instead [localhost]. Something like http://myserver.mydomain.org:8080

The full server name is obteined from MyPC/properties